# Tunneling could not be done in putty for multiple times to access non-directly accessible server

Tags: ssh, proxy, putty, tunnel

I have a problem that host2 cannot be connected directly from the local host and it can be accessed through host1 only. So I used tunneling concept in ssh of putty from my local host. It worked fine and I was able to access host2. Next time,When I give the same port as the previous session or different port number in port forwarding option under tunneling in putty, not able to access host2. It says connection timed out. Is there any problem in port number given? Similarly I tried with proxy option in putty to connect, very first time connected. When doing the same process not able to access host2. Not able to find the problem. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You could try using openssh from cygwin, and then you can copy/paste from the command line, showing the issue.  I'm not convinced that putty offers any advantage.. a GUI make sense for a word processor or a painting program.. it's less useful for a console..and less so for creating a tunnel..  And once you're using openssh you're on stronger ground 'cos lots of experts use it.  And diagnosis is easier because it's all commands you can fire off. And openssh isn't really harder than putty, but will give you more understanding of what's going on.

Comment: And if you really want to use putty, then perhaps screenshots of the issues and the values in various windows might help

Comment: Also ry to access the shell.. if you can't do that (and you don't have some weird setting(s) on the server that'd prevent it), then the thing stopping you wouldn't have anything to do with tunneling